# docker run container disappear in windows VM

Tags: docker, hyper-v, server-core

I'm running on a windows host different server core VMs (hyper-v) and in each one docker service. The containers I try to run, using `docker run nanoserver/iis-php` command, are created but immediately disappear, exited with exit code 0, no error messages. Since it happens in different VMs, I believe it is something in the VMs host. Any idea?

Comment: If you can see the containers using `docker ps -a`, then you can also see the logs with `docker logs <container name>` and maybe get a hint at why they exit immediately.

Comment: thanks for the reply, docker ps -a shows the container status is exited. docker logs gives me nothing just :                                  
 Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?  Without some description of what you're running (Dockerfiles, `docker run` commands, _etc._) it's a little hard to tell what might be going on.

Comment: so after searching a little bit the web, i understand that the 0 exit code means there is no process in the vms attached to the containers. can it be a nested virtualization configuration issue?

Comment: There's a strong possibility that there is nothing _in_ the container you're running. I'm not great with `php` but i'd imagine you'd need an `index.php` or some `php` code to run _in_ the container. How are you copying the code in?

Comment: I've to admit I've no clue, but suspect two options: 1) you've to install docker in each of these VMs or 2) make the global Docker installation available inside the VMs. Beside that it's usually enough to run docker on the host-machine and not in the VMs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to https://hub.docker.com/r/nanoserver/iis-php
use `docker run --name nanoiis -d -it -p 80:80 nanoserver/iis-php`
so that the container is started in daemon mode, interactive mode and with tty

I do not know iis-php, but from  the dockerfile of the image below, the last command is just to make webrequet, do not see any server process started.
https://github.com/nanoserver/IIS-PHP/blob/master/Dockerfile/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

> the containers [...] are created but immediately disappear, exited with exit code `0`, no error messages.

So as I understand they don't *disappear* but simply exit immediately with an exit code of 0 which you still can see with `docker ps -a`?

The exit code `0` indicates "success". So it looks like the containers were created and started successfully and the processes started in them executed "successfully". But what this means depends an the actual command started in the containers.

But neither the [`Dockerfile` of the `nanoserver/iis-php` image](https://github.com/nanoserver/IIS-PHP/blob/master/Dockerfile/Dockerfile) nor the [`Dockerfile` of its base image `nanoserver/iis`](https://github.com/nanoserver/iis/blob/master/Dockerfile) specify a [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd). Also no command is specified in your `docker run` command.

> docker logs gives me nothing just: `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393] (c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. C:\>`

This looks like an interactive command prompt expecting user input. So what most probably is happening here is that the containers start a simple interactive shell since no other command to execute is explicitly specified. But since  no `stdin` is attached to the container it can not read any input and will exit again.

You can test that the containers / your `docker` setup is working correctly with

```sh
docker run -ti nanoserver/iis-php
```

This should drop you into the interactive shell inside the container. You could then *interactively* execute commands in the container.

In order to have it run in the background you have to pass and command to execute to `docker run`

```sh
# this is just an example! The exact command you need
# depends on what you actually want to run inside the container
docker run -d nanoserver/iis-php php index.php
```